# Почему выдается ошибка: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Задача данного куска программы - раскрасить точки, указанные в цикле, но почему то она выдает ошибку

> Setting an array element with a sequence

на сроке  `img[x,y] = [0,255,0]`

```py
import cv2

import numpy as np

import math as m

import skimage.io as io

import skimage.transform as trans

from model import unet

import datetime as d

from PIL import Image
...

io.imsave (outName, resModel)

img_original = cv2.imread(filename,1)

img_original_b = cv2.imread(filename,0)

#цветное изображение раскрасски
img_rgb      = cv2.imread(outName,1)

# Для восстановления модели, на которой рисовать
img_rgb_Kas = img_rgb.copy()

# черно-белое изображение раскрасски
img      = cv2.imread(outName,0)

...
  
for x in range (int(M_end[0]),int(B_end[0])+1):
        y = (-a/b)*x - c/b

        y = int(y)

        img[x,y] = [0,255,0]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# черно-белое изображение раскрасски
img      = cv2.imread(outName,0)
...
img[x,y] = [0,255,0]
```

Вопрос: **сколько компонент** у одного пиксела **чёрно-белого** изображения? Ответ: у него ровно одна компонента - **яркость**, это **одно** число. А вы пытаетесь присвоить элементу массива, в котором должно быть одно число, **список из трёх чисел** (видимо, это компоненты RGB). Поэтому и возникает такая ошибка:

```
Setting an array element with a sequence
```

Скорее всего, вы хотели рисовать на каком-то другом изображении.

Кстати, я проверил свои рассуждения:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('result.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
print(im[0,0])
im = cv2.imread('result.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
print(im[0,0])
```

Вывод:

```
[255 255 255]
255
```

В случае, если мы читаем картинку как цветную - получаем три компоненты на пиксел. А если читаем как чёрно-белую - получаем одну компоненту, как я и говорил.

P.S. И ещё не используйте "магические константы", например `0` вместо именованной константы `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`. Когда читаешь код, что такое параметр `0` у функции `imread` - непонятно, а вот если написать `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` - уже сразу понятно, что это за параметр.

Comment: Crazy, Elf спасибо вам 